# How do I group by factor level and select only the most recent value?

Tags: r, dplyr

I am using R to analyse blood results for a population of patients, the electronic health record outputs all values for all patients with the date that they were taken on.

I want to select only the latest value for each patient. I have cleaned up the data using `dplyr` so if anyone knows a way of achieving this using `dplyr` I'd be really grateful.

**Currently the data looks like this:**

```
date, patient_id, value
13-01-2012, 345678,  13.2
23-06-2013, 345678,  10.3
12-02-2014, 345678,  9.6
1-03-2010, 789012,  22.3
28-02-2011, 789012,  10.3
6-04-2012, 789012,  8.2
```

**And what I would like to select is:**

```
date, patient_id, value
12-02-2014, 345678,  9.6
6-04-2012, 789012,  8.2
```

Comment: not sure what this has to do with dplyr `x[!duplicated(x$patient_id, fromLast = TRUE), ]`

Comment: @rawr, go ahead and post as an answer ... (PS yours assumes the data are properly sorted by date within patient ...)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As @Gregor says, this is easy if your date variable is actually a `Date`-class object.

```
x <- read.csv(text="
date, patient_id, value
13-01-2012, 345678, 13.2
23-06-2013, 345678, 10.3
12-02-2014, 345678, 9.6
1-03-2010, 789012, 22.3
28-02-2011, 789012, 10.3
6-04-2012, 789012, 8.2",
colClasses=c("character","character","numeric"))

library("dplyr")
x %>% 
   ## convert to date
   mutate(date=as.Date(date,format="%d-%m-%Y")) %>%
   ## group by patient and take only most recent
   group_by(patient_id) %>% filter(date==max(date))
```

@Gregor pointed out (he's now deleted his answer) that

```
   order_by(desc(date)) %>% slice(1)
```

would work as an alternative to `filter(date==max(date))` (not sure whether there's any significant difference in efficiency)

Comment: @SofaMonkey, SO convention is to *not* use comments to say "thank you" (the sentiment is appreciated) - instead, accept (click the check-mark) and/or upvote to show your appreciation ...

Comment: Also, `dplyr` provides a `top_n` function, so `top_n(1, date)` is another option.  Both `top_n` and `filter(date==max(date))` have the problem where duplicate fields will result in two results being returned; but the `slice` answer requires an `arrange(date)` in order to be correct.

Comment: Almost equivalent answers, but you beat me by a smidge :)  Thanks for incorporating the elements of difference!